# How to find list of word and their stems in Hindi language

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, hindi

I am doing NLP project on the Hindi language, where I have to find stems/root word of given word.My approach is to build a deep neural network.But for that, I need label data of words and their root words.I am unable to find proper resources(dataset).where do I find these resources

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try Hindi to English Dictionary Websites for feeding data ,which can be converted from HTML to CSV format. But lot of Data cleaning will be needed , But it may work out.